# Plugin's dependency not found in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I'm trying to centralize my Java's Checkstyle configuration by using the following plugin configuration in my pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- Checkstyle Plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.myorganization</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
        <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The checkstyle-config dependency is a simple maven project with the checkstyle.xml config as a resource, but the problem is that this project is in a custom/private repository, and if it is not locally cached, it doesn't work. If I go to my checkstyle-config project and run `mvn install`, it works as it should, but if I clear the cache and run `mvn verify` in my main project, the config dependency is not resolved.

Any ideas?

Obs1: I created another test project and added my config project as a dependency (without using the checkstyle plugin) and it is resolved and downloaded.

Obs2: me.myorganization is just a placeholder to protect the original one.

Obs3: I have already tried adding the dependency in both places, in the plugin's dependencies and in the normal pom dependencies, and it still doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you run `mvn package verify`?

Comment: Also doesn't work :(

Comment: I suggested that to make sure `generate-sources` and `dependency:resolve` were being run.  I'm sorry it wasn't any help.

Comment: Did you set up your organisation's repository in either your pom.xml or settings.xml? Have you tried running Maven with `mvn -X verify`?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add in the your pom file pluginRepositories block with your repository of the checkstyle-config artifact. f.e.

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>myorganization-repo</id>
        <url>https://nexus.myorganization.local/repository/myorganization-repo/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```